# How to find from array list in one-many relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have one-many 2 of domain class,

```
class Company {
    String name
    static hasMany = [groups:CompanyGroup]
}

class CompanyGroup {
    String name 
    static belongsTo = [company:Company]
}
```

I receive a list of CompanyGroup from below code,

```
def groupList = CompanyGroup.withCriteria{
    users{
        eq 'id', new Long(user.id)
    }
}
```

And I want to find which Companies has these groupList. I try this way,

```
def comList
groupList.each(){ group ->
    def coms = Company.withCriteria{
        eq("groups", group)
    }
    comList.collect{[coms]} 
} 
println 'company : ' + comList
```

It didn't work anymore.

Comment: What do you mean "It didn't work anymore"?  What was the expected vs. actual output?

Comment: Once you have groupList cant you just collect companies like this groupList.collect { it.company }

Answer (score 0):

How about this hql

```
Company.executeQuery("select c from company c join c.groups g join g.users u where u.id = :uid", [uid:xxx])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this GORM Query.

```
def companyInstanceList = Company.createCriteria().listDistinct{
    groups{
        users{
         eq ('id', user.id.toLong())
        }
    }
}
```